# Why is my sprite blurred when using requestAnimationFrame to move it?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I created a basic 2D game using pure JavaScript. My problem is when the sprite stops moving it is sometimes blurred sometimes not. I use `requestAnimationFrame` to move the sprite and `keydown/keyup` events trigger moving. When keyup is triggered the sprite stops moving and the default tile is set however sometimes it is showing blurred.
https://arpadvas.github.io/untitled_game_project/

Comment: which browser? works fine in firefox windows 64bit

Comment: It's maybe your monitor's gray to gray transition

Comment: Can you post screenshots of the problem?

Comment: I use Chrome but the same problem exists in IE as well.

Comment: I'm linking another screenshot. First one is good, second one is blurred.

Comment: https://s15.postimg.org/4ftg31kp7/error.jpg

Comment: We'll need to see some code, and we probably won't go through your 700 line codes. Try to create an [MCVE] and add it as an [edit] to your question. A blind guess (*actually not so blind, it works in my console*) : you probably are drawing your sprite on floating values. You can fix it by either rounding all coordinates, or if you're lazy, you can also just set the [`imageSmoothingEnabled`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) property of your context to false. (Note that you still need vendor prefixes so it works everywhere).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you didn't posted an minimal code example, and that I don't want to go through the raw code you linked to, this will stay as a guess (an educated one).

Generally, this happens when you draw your sprites on floating coordinates.
Since there is no way to draw on half a pixel, the pixel being the smallest unit in canvas, to smoothen drawings, the browser will by default create antialias artifacts, turning some pixels less opaque so that your eyes think it is on half a pixel. 
While this usually works well with realistic photographs, it doesn't at all with pixel-art.

The solution then is either to round all your coordinates, or if you are lazy, to set the [imageSmoothingEnabled](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/imageSmoothingEnabled) property of your context.

```js
var img = new Image();
img.onload = draw;

function draw(){
  i = .316252;
  blurred.width = round.width = noAntiAlias.width = img.width +20;
  blurred.height = round.height = noAntiAlias.height = img.height +20;
  blurred.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 10+i, 20+i);
  round.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 10, 20);
  var nA = noAntiAlias.getContext('2d');
  nA.mozImageSmoothingEnabled = nA.msImageSmoothingEnabled = nA.webkitImageSmoothingEnabled = nA.imageSmoothingEnabled = false;
  noAntiAlias.getContext('2d').drawImage(img, 10+i, 20+i);
};
img.src = "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/4e90e48s5vtmfbd/aaa.png";
```

```html
<canvas id="blurred"></canvas>
<canvas id="round"></canvas>
<canvas id="noAntiAlias"></canvas>
```

Ps : this made me realize that somehow my FF doesn't smooth this particular image I used... If someone can confirm in comments, I'd be glad to dig into this further if needed.

Comment: I actually found that FF does disable imageSmoothing on canvas smaller than 128*128px, weird.